# Two questions on the Grothendieck ring of varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

1) In the definition of the Grothendieck ring of varieties over a field $k$, which definition of the various notions of "variety" is chosen? Finite type and separated, or maybe more?

2) If $\mathbb{L}$ is the class of the affine line in the Grothendieck ring, does the class of $\mathrm{GL}_n$ equal $(\mathbb{L}^n - 1) \cdot \dotsc \cdot (\mathbb{L}^n - \mathbb{L}^{n-1})$? Somehow this should be true, but for this I would need a "fibration relation", which does not seem to follow from the scissor relation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little comment which does not seem to involve algebraic spaces. 
All I am saying here I learnt in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.4372v1.pdf).

Basically, given any two Zariski fibrations $\pi_i:X_i\to Y$, $i=1,2$, with *the same fiber* $F$, one has the relation $[X_1]=[X_2]$ in the Grothendieck ring. Indeed, one can stratify the base $Y=\coprod_j U_j$ (these $U_j$'s being connected locally closed subvarieties) so that $\pi_i:{\pi_i^{-1}(U_j)\to U_j}$ are trivial, thus $$[X_1]=\sum_j[\pi_1^{-1}(U_j)]=\sum_j([U_j]\cdot [F])=\sum_j[\pi_2^{-1}(U_j)]=[X_2].$$ Both classes equal $[Y]\cdot [F]$.

---

The fact that $$[\textrm{GL}_n]=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(\mathbb L^n-\mathbb L^i)$$ can be proved by induction. For $n=1$ it is clear. For arbitrary $n$, use the fibration $\pi:\textrm{GL}_n\to \mathbb C^n\setminus 0$ sending a matrix to its first column, say. The fiber is $\textrm{GL}_{n-1}\times \mathbb C^{n-1}$, so you can write $[\textrm{GL}_n]=(\mathbb L^n-1)\cdot \mathbb L^{n-1}\cdot [\textrm{GL}_{n-1}]$, and you can conclude by induction.

If you work with Grothendieck rings, it might be interesting to know that the classes $[\textrm{GL}_n]$ are exactly the classes you need to invert in $K_0(\textrm{Var}_k)$ in order to get the Grothendieck ring of stacks:
$$K_0(\textrm{Var}_k)[[\textrm{GL}_n]^{-1}\,|\,n\geq 1]\cong K_0(\textrm{St}_k).$$

---

For your question (1), unfortunately I do not know enough literature to guess what is the most common definition of variety. But *reduced* seems redundant to me. Indeed, the closed immersion $X_{\textrm{red}}\to X$ has empty open complement, and the scissor relation then tells you $[X]=[X_{\textrm{red}}]$.

Comment: I really like that description of the Grothendieck ring of algebraic stacks (where one, by the way, *demands* a fiber relation). $\mathrm{GL}_n$ gets inverted via its classifying stack $\mathrm{BGL}_n$, and somehow "that's all"!

Comment: True, a fiber relation must be imposed in the stacks picture!

Comment: Why can we find a partition into *disjoint* locally closed subvarieties on which the fibration is trivial?

Comment: If $X\to Y$ has *constant fiber* $F$, there must be a way to chop off $Y$ so that this is true. I cannot figure it out at the moment, but I'll think more later.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've read, it seems like separated and finite type are fairly standard. Poonen, in his paper "The Grothendieck Ring of Varieties is not a Domain" adds geometrically reduced- I haven't seen this other places, but I haven't looked too hard.

For the second, there does exist a fibration relation- seeing it is difficult without going to more complicated categories with isomorphic Grothendieck rings. Consider the inclusion $\mathrm{Var}_k\to\mathrm{Space}_k$- this gives rise to a homomorphism of grothendieck rings, which turns out to be an isomorphism. The following argument then works in the category of algebraic spaces over $k$, and the relation in fact holds in the Grothendieck ring of varieties:

Consider a fibration $E\to B$ with fiber $F$. In the category of algebraic spaces, there exists an open set $U\subset B$ such that $E_U\to U$ is isomorphic to $U\times F\to U$. Let  $V= B\setminus U$, a closed subset of $B$. So we have $[E]=[F][U]+[E_V]$, and by noetherian induction, we may say that $[E_V]=[F][V]$, and so $[E]=[F][B]$. Now you can apply the argument you seem to have in mind in (2).

Comment: "There exists an open set $U \subset B$ such that..." No, that is not true. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/158424/fibrations-with-isomorphic-fibers-but-not-zariski-locally-trivial

Comment: Oh dear- you're correct. On the other hand, this statement is true in the category of Algebraic spaces, which has an isomorphic Grothendieck ring (the isomorphism is given by the natural inclusion). I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What is a reference for the observation that algebraic spaces (finite type and separated?) have the same Grothendick ring? Also, what is a more direct way to compute the class of $\mathrm{GL}_n$?

Comment: I can't find a textbook reference for the isomorphism currently. I have heard it said with confidence by several professors, and http://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.5404.pdf contains the same claim. Moreover, proposition 2.3 in section 2.1 has a "neater" way to see the class of $GL_n$ - I'm not sure it is more direct, but it is different. I hope this is helpful.